# Merge partitions between logical and extended partition

Tags: ubuntu, gparted

I'm not sure how to merge that unallocated 5GB space with the ext4 partition (sda5). Is there is a way (without formatting the ext4 filesystem)?

[image: gparted screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GParted, you can move the beginning of the extended partition. Just use the “Resize/Move” button on the extended partition and set “Free space preceding” to 0.

Then use the “Resize/Move” button to move the ext4 partition to the beginning of the extended partition and enlarge it.

You can't (or at least shouldn't, I'm not sure if GParted would outright prevent you) do that if the partition is in use. Boot from a live CD/USB such as [GParted Live](http://gparted.org/livecd.php).

In the future, for more flexibility with partitions, use [LVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_(Linux)). It's easier to resize partitions, they don't have to occupy consecutive disk space, manipulations are less error-prone and you can often do it from the live system. You can convert your existing system to LVM, but that's difficult; it's a lot easier to do it at the time you install. (If your distribution doesn't support installing to LVM, throw it away.)

Comment: I solved with an ubuntu live usb I had. Here you can resize the extended partition on left.
I didn't know I can't resize an active partition (on windows usually you can, the utilities simply postpone the operation on the next reboot)

Answer (score 0):

Either

1) Copy all the data out of the Linux partition, wipe it, create a new partition table and restore, OR

2) You could remove the swap partition, and recreate a new `sda3` in the empty spot, create a filesystem on it, mount it somewhere on your system and use it for storing data files.

I wouldn't go into messing around with the existing partition and trying to move it, if anything on that disk is dear to you.

Comment: basically there is no way to merge those partitions? On ext4 there is no data, just a whole OS configured as a pseudo-distributed machine (hadoop). It's kind of crazy format the partition and reconfigure it..